# is there an easy way to make dataframes look nice?

Tags: r, function, tidyr

I have a dataframe and the structure is nice for some purpoes, but absolutly not for GGPLOT. is there an function to transform

```
x <- data.frame(head_1 = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
           head_2 = c(4,5,6,1,2,3),
            date = c("01-01-2019","01-01-2019","01-01-2019","02-01-2019","02-01-2019","02-01-2019"))
```

Into

```
y <- data.frame(type= c("head_1","head_1","head_1","head_1","head_1","head_1",
                    "head_2","head_2","head_2","head_2","head_2","head_2"),
            date = c("01-01-2019", "01-01-2019","01-01-2019","01-01-2019","01-01-2019","01-01-2019",
                     "02-01-2019", "02-01-2019","02-01-2019","02-01-2019","02-01-2019","02-01-2019"),
            value= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3 ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the new `pivot_longer` function in the tidyr package revision >1.0 can perform the transformation in one line.

```
library(tidyr)
y<-pivot_longer(x, cols = starts_with("head"), names_to = "type", values_to = "value")

y

 A tibble: 12 x 3
   date       type   value
   <fct>      <chr>  <dbl>
 1 01-01-2019 head_1     1
 2 01-01-2019 head_2     4
 3 01-01-2019 head_1     2
 4 01-01-2019 head_2     5
 5 01-01-2019 head_1     3
 6 01-01-2019 head_2     6
 7 02-01-2019 head_1     1
 8 02-01-2019 head_2     1
 9 02-01-2019 head_1     2
10 02-01-2019 head_2     2
11 02-01-2019 head_1     3
12 02-01-2019 head_2     3
```

Comment: curious @DaveT, `gather()` would also do the trick, just longer?

Comment: Yes, `gather` would also work, but the future direction of the tidyr package is move away from `gather/separate` to the `pivot_wider` & `pivot_longer`.  The new pivot functions are more powerful than their older counterparts.

Comment: https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/1108107722128613377?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1108107722128613377&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.r-bloggers.com%2Fpivoting-data-frames-just-got-easier-thanks-to-pivot_wide-and-pivot_long%2F

Comment: The boss has spoken

Comment: @DaveT I have a question, I would have personally simply use ``melt()`` from data.table. Is there any reason I should use those ``pivot()`` functions instead?

Comment: @Gainz, There are many ways to solve this problem.  My datasets aren't large enough to see the advantages of using data.tables thus I generally stick with dplyr and tidyr functions.  I suggest going to the tidyverse web site to understand the pro, cons and the future direction.

Comment: @DaveT Thanks, I was simply wondering since I'm used to the ``data.table`` package but I noticed the tidyr/dplyr packages are a lot more popular on stack and it's been a while since I used ``dplyr``.